Resize ColumnDefinition when IsMouseOver Element
I'm trying to make a grid column occupy most of the window when the user's cursor is over a Border element.
Example of the mouse on the right side border

However, I can't get the ColumnDefintion.Width to change
I've stipped most things from the XAML code
I'd be grateful for any pointers/solutions
<Page x:Class="Together_Culture_CRM.LoginRegister"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Together_Culture_CRM"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="LoginRegister">

    <Page.Resources>
        
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="LeftCollum" Width="4*">
                <ColumnDefinition.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="PanelSwipe"
                           TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LeftBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.1">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ColumnDefinition.Resources>
            </ColumnDefinition>


            <ColumnDefinition Name="RightCollum" Width="4*">
                <ColumnDefinition.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="PanelSwipe"
                           TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RightBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="1" Duration="00:00:20">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ColumnDefinition.Resources>
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Name="LeftBorder"
                Margin="20,20,10,20">
        </Border>

        <Border Name="RightBorder"
                Margin="10,20,20,20"
                Grid.Column="1">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Page>


You made multiple mistakes:

Storing a named Style in an element's resources does not apply the Style to the element.

The type of ColumnDefinition.Width is not double but GridLenth and thus you need to use ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames to change it.


The modified ColumnDefinitin (left only) will be as follows:
<ColumnDefinition Name="LeftCollum" Width="4*">
    <ColumnDefinition.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ColumnDefinition}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LeftBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                               Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                               FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <GridLength>1*</GridLength>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <GridLength>4*</GridLength>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ColumnDefinition.Style>
</ColumnDefinition>


Thank you so much for the feedback, I'll run it now
